# How to hide the table according filter number in the content?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have problem to hide the table is follow the Category/Cabinet number are range 100-199 and range 400-499.

Below is my example coding to describe, these example have 3 table, how to detect if range 100-199 and range 400-499 in the Category/Cabinet then hide the table:

```html
<table id="noshow">
  <tr>
    <th>Test 1</th>
    <th>Test 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>ABC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Reference No.</td>
    <td>123456</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>28-05-2020</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category/Cabinet</td>
    <td>187-1-PENTADBIRAN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Subcategory/Folder</td>
    <td>187-1-1-PENTADBIRAN/PERUNDANGAN</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br><br>

<table id="noshow">
  <tr>
    <th>Test 3</th>
    <th>Test 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>DEF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Reference No.</td>
    <td>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>27-05-2020</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category/Cabinet</td>
    <td>356-1-PENTADBIRAN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Subcategory/Folder</td>
    <td>356-1-1-PENTADBIRAN/PERUNDANGAN</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br><br>

<table id="noshow">
  <tr>
    <th>Test 5</th>
    <th>Test 6</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>GHI</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Reference No.</td>
    <td>8888</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>23-05-2020</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category/Cabinet</td>
    <td>466-1-PENTADBIRAN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Subcategory/Folder</td>
    <td>466-1-1-PENTADBIRAN/PERUNDANGAN</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have using below the javascirpt to solve, but can't hide the table:

```html
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#noshow').each(function(k,v){
             var number=$(v).text().split('-')[0];
            console.log(number,$(v).text());
            if((number >= 100 && number <= 199)||(number >= 400 && number <= 499)){
                console.log("remove");
               $(v).remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

My output like below the picture:

[image: Output 1]

**If success, the result only left not range 100-199 and range 400-499 to show the table like below the picture:**

[image: Output 3]

If possible using the javascript function to hide the data?Hope someone can guide me how to hide the table according the Category/Cabinet number are range 100-199 and range 400-499. Thanks.

Comment: This is too broad of a question. We are not here to give you full-on tutorials, you need to lay at least some of the ground work yourself.

Comment: show some javascript code you wrote to render this table

Comment: @CBroe I have tried to add javascript updated in above

Comment: @ShijilNarayan I have updated my javascript in the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.noshow tr td').each(function (k, v) {
    var title = $(v).text();
    if (title === 'Category/Cabinet') {
        var number = parseInt($(this).next().text().split('-')[0])
        if ((number >= 100 && number <= 199) || (number >= 400 && number <= 499)) {
            $(this).closest('.noshow').remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Also change `noShow` to `class` and not `id`, as we should not have multiple id with same name in the dom

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vfwxgLmo/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I've tried my side still cannot work

Comment: Did you change `<table id="noshow">` to `<table class="noshow">`?

Comment: I have attached a jsfiddle link in the ans , pls check

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But why all the border no show? Just show work only

Comment: i have not added the css, with css in place it will show the borders as well